# Can't use objects from a worksheet when the worksheet is declared

Tags: vba, excel

So The following works

```
Sheet1.btnAfkeurMin.Visible = True
```

Below is what doesn't work

```
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If cmbDate.Value = WS.Name Then
         WS.btnAfkeurMin.Visible = True
    end if
next
```

cmdDate.Value and WS.Name are the same. (Checked in console)
How do I call btnAfkeurMin while using WS?

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"?  Do you get an error or do you get unexpected results?  Are `cmbDate` and `btnAfkeurMin1 a combobox and button, respectively?

Comment: @JoshuaRoss I get an error, something about method not found. It's in dutch though. They are indeed a combobox and a button.

Comment: Did you declare the variables `cmbDate` and `btnAfkeurMin`?

Comment: @JoshuaRoss Yes, remember that the code works just fine if I use the actual name of the sheet instead of WS, but I need to loop through all sheets

Comment: The reason I ask is because `btnAfkeurMin` is set once wherever you do that, and even though you are changing worksheets you don't appear to be changing buttons.  The way that I am reading it is that there is a button on each sheet, but the `btnAfkeurmin` is not changing definition as the worksheet changes.

Comment: Every sheet has the same button called btnAfkeurMin. But I guess you're looking in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the issue is caused because `btnAfkeurmin` is only assigned once.  As you loop through the worksheets, you need to re-reference the new button on the new sheet.

For example, this code will loop through each sheet and hide all of the buttons named btnAfkeurmin.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFormControls()

        Dim WS As Worksheet

        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                WS.Shapes("btnAfkeurMin").Visible = msoFalse
        Next WS

End Sub
```

Adapting to your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestFormControls()
        Dim WS As Worksheet

        For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If cmbDate.Value = WS.Name Then
                 WS.Shapes("btnAfkeurMin").Visible = True
            End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Similar logic applies if you need to reference different comboboxes named `cmbDate`.  If you are always referencing the single one that is declared earlier in the code, this is fine (which I gather is what's happening based on your statement that `cmbDate.Value = WS.Name` evaluates to true).

But if, for some reason, you had a different combobox on each sheet that you needed to reference you would do so in the same way with:

`WS.Shapes("cmbDate").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
WS.OLEObjects("btnAfkeurMin").Visible = True
```

If you want to use the Object directly then you can also use this

```
Worksheets(WS.Name).btnAfkeurMin.Visible = True
```